# [Aero-Peek], [Aero-Snap], and [Aero], one and the same?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Shouldn't the tags [aero-peek](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/aero-peek), [aero-snap](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/aero-snap), and [aero](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/aero) just fall under [aero](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/aero)..? Maybe we could combine them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[aero-peek](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/aero-peek) and [aero-snap](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/aero-snap) cater to different features, and as such I believe should remain separate.

I have created a synonym for [aero](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/aero) as [windows-aero](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-aero)

Answer (score 3):

I would love to see [windows-aero](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-aero) and [aero](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/aero) merged.

But I think [aero-peek](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/aero-peek) and [aero-snap](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/aero-snap) might benefit as being more specific tags...