# Merge [aero-snap] and [windows-snap-assist]

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tag-synonym-request

[aero-snap](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/aero-snap) has 44 questions whereas there are only 7 questions in [windows-snap-assist](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-snap-assist). They're small enough that none of them has a wiki. They're all about [snapping feature](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/snap-your-windows-885a9b1e-a983-a3b1-16cd-c531795e6241) in [Windows Aero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Aero)

[aero](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/aero) and [windows-aero](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-aero) has been merged. We should also merge those together

Related: [[Aero-Peek], [Aero-Snap], and [Aero], one and the same?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/2036/241386)